# How can defined global variable that will be recognized in all php file (Case inside)?

Tags: php

How can defined global variable ($begin) that will be recognized in all php file?
(please dont change the case code only add, because I working on big project that i can only add code)

***Case:(problem $begin not recognized in the end of the file)***

```
<?php $begin=time()?>
  <div>new name</div>
<?php   echo time()-$begin; ?>
```

Edit:
I have stupid mistake in file, now the code works, thanks

Thanks

Comment: Hint: Maybe you overwrite it somewhere? btw what do you mean "in all php file"?

Comment: What do you mean by "not recognized"? What exact error message do you get? Do you define $begin inside a function? Or in an if statement maybe?

Comment: all the PHP file, I think he means the whole compile of the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use, constants as they have global scope.

```
<?php define('TS_START',time())?>
  <div>new name</div>
<?php   echo time()-TS_START; ?>
```

or if you cant do that because of your "large" project. maybe you want to double var it.

```
<?php $begin = $_begin = $__begin = time()?>
  <div>new name</div>
<?php   echo time()- ($begin ? $begin : ($_begin ? $_begin : $__begin)); ?>
```

poor programming though, there's no need for that many vars for one small entity, I would rewrite with define and overwrite all instances of `$begin` with `TS_START`

Answer (score 2):

It's probably a good idea to set up a configuration file that's stored alongside the scripts you use, and then include that file at the top of every script. For example, this could be the content of a file named `config.php` at the same directory level as the scripts you're using:

```
<?php

$begin = time();

?>
```

You can then add the following line to the top of every PHP file that needs to access the variable:

```
<?php include 'config.php'; ?>
```

If you want to make sure you don't use that variable by mistake in a script, you can use the `define` functionality instead. It works in a very similar way, but it's more permanent. You could put this in the configuration file:

```
<?php

define('BEGIN', time());

?>
```

And then any script that has the include mentioned above could simply include this code:

```
<?php echo time() - BEGIN; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

With the example you've given, there's no reason why $begin shouldn't still be valid at the end of the program.

- Have you checked that you're not using the name $begin for something else within your program?
- Similarly, you may be including some third-party code which uses $begin? Either way, consider changing the variable name you're using to a more unique one.
- In the example, all your code is in the global scope. But if your real code uses functions for these, then $begin would be at the function-level scope, so wouldn't be global.
  In this case, the quickest option would be to add global $begin; at the top of both functions.